# Best_in_place gem, defining a fixed input field using css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

I am using best_in_place gem which is awesome for inplace editing in rails apps.
But the problem with my implementation is the area that is defined as best in place wraps only around the text and so due to which there is some kind of **wobbling**[1] effect if I try to edit some desired field. So is there any way where in I can make the fixed text_area size so that it stays with the width that I want.

[1] By wobbling I mean when I click on the field i.e., when the field is focus it is of some width and when I tab-out it goes to default wrapper size.

Answer (score 6):

The key is defining the inner class, rather than just the class. As in:

user/show.html.erb:

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :name, :inner_class => "css_class" %>
```

custom.css:

```
.css_class {
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, but I had kind of similar problem (same problem but with the text field), and this is how I've resolved it:

First add class to the best_in_place field:
`<%= best_in_place @your_variable, :name, { :classes => "input_field" } %>`

(I work with best_in_place 2.1.0, for older version you would need to depend on the id of the field, which seems to be unique)

Then apply styling to the **input** child of the class in your css:

`.input_field input {
    width: 400px;
}`

and that should do it.